# Which directory in my path is causing Qt to think I am using Q_OS_LINUX and not Q_OS_WIN?

Tags: windows, path, qt-creator

## Background

I am currently using QtCreator in Windows, so one of the [Q_OS_WIN](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_OS_WIN) favmily of variables should be defined in the Qt Environment.  However, I am getting a meta object compiled file that should only be created when [Q_OS_LINUX](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_OS_LINUX) is true.  I have solved this in the past and it was because I had cygwin in my path. However, this time, I do not know which directory in my path would trick Qt into thinking I am using linux.

## Question

Which path(s) are the ones that would trick Qt into thinking I am using Linux?

```
C:\Strawberry\c\bin;
C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zulu\zulu-8-jre\bin\;
C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-8-jre\bin\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\mpirt;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\compiler;
%F_IA32_REDIST11%bin\ia32;
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Program Files\IcedTeaWeb\WebStart\bin;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\dotnet\;
C:\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Pulse Secure\VC142.CRT\X64\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Pulse Secure\VC142.CRT\X86\;
C:\Program Files\cmake-3.20.0;
C:\Program Files\ninja.exe;
C:\omake;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
```

Comment: Move the `%SystemRoot%\system32` entry first, any program that installs itself ahead of the OS is acting malicious.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good for pointing that out, it did not resolve my issue though.